# How do almanacs predict future natural calamities?

Tags: scripture, astrology, panchang

Almanacs are a mathematical tool for calculating thithis, stars, yogams and karnams. Apart from these a one year prediction is also given for example - this year there will be more rain eg. In the south west of Vindhyas there will be a severe cyclonic storm in the karthika month and 75% of the rains will be in sea, 15% in mountains and remaining in the vilages and cities adjacent to them.

On what basis is this prediction being done? There are Vakiya panchangam, Thiru Ganitha Panchangam, Pambu panchangam etc.Again I think this may vary from region to region. Any scriptural evidence as to how they calculate and predict the natural calamities?

Comment: I think the creators of Almanacs or Panchangas form kundalies of different regions based on Longitude and latitude etc. And they predect the likely future events like Rain , natural calamity , food production , market condiation by examining " sun's  entering in which perticular Nakshatra ,"Vahanas" of that nakshatra eg.(Hasta, Mruga) etc. They calculate muhurtas for starting of new work , agricultural work etc. according to "Maha Dasha" , Antardasha.

Comment: Also by sering "Who is swami or Adhipati" of seasons , name of the clouds eg.(neelak) etc.That is called "Samvatsara Phala" or fruits of Samvatsara.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar The comment given by you serves 25% of the answer. Any scriptural evidence is there how the panchank is made.

Comment: ok , tried to find scriptural source , but yet not found. I think it needs lots of previous Panchangas and events , their info etc.and based on that info.these people prepare panchanga ,lots of mathematics and old data also is involved, so overall this is complicated process.

Comment: Natural calamities can be predicted by calculating the angular distance between planets, they form conjunctions, trine, oppositions and square. Whatever happens in future is all based on past events, when those past events happen then conjunctions, trine etc.. are calculated between various planets and they are verified with reality when such calamities happen.